# Crash when text is drawn using XFT Fonts the second time with a new display connection in the same application process

Tags: fonts, x11, xorg

I was trying to use XFT for my application, but it crashes the second time I try to draw the text with a new display connection inside the same process. The following is simplified version of my use case.

```
while true
do
    OpenDisplay
    LoadFont
    Draw Text
    Close Font   
    Close Display
end
```

I read in a few forums that XCloseDisplay will also close the fonts, but I noticed memory leak when I tried that with multiple fonts loaded.

I tried to debug the issue and these were my observations,

1. Comment XftDrawText, crash disappears
2. Comment XftFontClose, crash disappears but leaks memory

Here is the code that I used to reproduce this. Any help will be appreciated.

```
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <X11/Xft/Xft.h>

using namespace std;

const char fontNames[5][50] = { "helvetica", "arial", "courier", "times", "utopia" };
int sizes[5] = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50};
int numFonts = 5;

void TestXft(Display* display, Window& win, GC& gc, const char *fontName, int size);

Window create_simple_window(Display* display, int width, int height, int x, int y)
{
    int screen_num = DefaultScreen(display);
    int win_border_width = 2;
    Window win;
    win = XCreateSimpleWindow(display, RootWindow(display, screen_num), x, y,
            width, height, win_border_width,
            BlackPixel(display, screen_num),
            WhitePixel(display, screen_num));

    XMapWindow(display, win);

    XFlush(display);

    return win;
}

GC create_gc(Display* display, Window win)
{
    GC gc;
    unsigned long valuemask = 0;
    XGCValues values;

    gc = XCreateGC(display, win, valuemask, &values);

    if (gc < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "XCreateGC: \n");
    }
    return gc;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int screen_num;
    Window win;
    unsigned int display_width, display_height;
    GC gc;
    unsigned long count = 0;

    while(true)
    {       
        cout << "\nIteration: " << ++count << endl;

        Display* display = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
        if (display == NULL)
        {
            printf("Cannot connect to X server\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        screen_num = DefaultScreen(display);
        display_width = 500;
        display_height = 500;

        win = create_simple_window(display, display_width, display_height, 0, 0);
        XMapWindow(display, win);

        XMoveWindow(display, win, 1000, 600);

        gc = create_gc(display, win);

        for(int i = 0; i < numFonts; i++)
        {
            TestXft(display, win, gc, fontNames[i], sizes[i]);
        }

        XUnmapWindow(display, win);
        XFreeGC(display, gc);
        XSync(display, false);
        XCloseDisplay(display);
    }
    return 0;
}

void TestXft(Display* display, Window& win, GC& gc, const char *fontName, int size)
{
    XftFont      *font = NULL;
    XftDraw      *xftdraw = NULL;
    XRenderColor xrcolor;
    XftColor     xftcolor;
    font = NULL;

    Colormap colormap = XCreateColormap(display, win, DefaultVisual(display, DefaultScreen(display)), AllocNone);

    font = XftFontOpen(display, DefaultScreen(display), XFT_FAMILY, XftTypeString, fontName,
                                XFT_SIZE, XftTypeDouble, (double) size,
                                XFT_SCALE, XftTypeDouble, 2.0,
                                NULL);
    if (!font)
    {
        printf("Font not Found.\n");
        return;
    }

    xftdraw = XftDrawCreate(display, win, DefaultVisual(display,0), colormap);

    xrcolor.red = 65535;
    xrcolor.green= 0;
    xrcolor.blue = 0;
    xrcolor.alpha= 65535;
    XftColorAllocValue(display, DefaultVisual(display,0), colormap, &xrcolor, &xftcolor);

    const char *text = "RCB...RCB...RCB";
    XftDrawString8(xftdraw, &xftcolor, font, 200, 300 , (XftChar8 *) text, strlen(text));

    XftColorFree(display, DefaultVisual(display,0), colormap, &xftcolor);
    XftDrawDestroy(xftdraw);
    XftFontClose(display, font);
    XFreeColormap(display, colormap);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug in the Xft library that prevents it from being useful when a display is opened and closed multiple times.

Move `XOpenDisplay` and `XCloseDisplay` out of the loop, add a call to `XDestroyWindow` and it will work.